# Java Timer. Отсчет времени после старта потока

Tags: java, многопоточность, таймер

Я использую `Timer` и устанавливаю таймер через метод `shedule()`, задавая повтор каждые `N` секунд. Но столкнулся с проблемой, мне необходимо запускать два таймера (а желательно и больше), так, чтобы отсчёт на каждом начинался ПОСЛЕ завершения работы `run()`, а не в момент его запуска.

Особенно это заметно, если один таймер тормозит другой из-за `synchronized` метода. И в результате один из таймеров повторно начинает свою работу не после `N` секунд от конца задачи, а через `N`-время работы второго таймера.

Как запускать таймер, после конца работы метода `run()`?

Код:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTimerTask(this), 2*1000, seconds*1000);
(+ также создается еще один таймер, с отличием в seconds)

public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    TemplateForBots bot;

    public MyTimerTask(TemplateForBots bot) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.bot = bot;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        locker(bot);

    }
    public static synchronized void locker(TemplateForBots bot) {
        System.out.println("I was locked by " + bot.getClass().getSimpleName() + " and it was " + new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()));
        bot.setTaskForTimer();
    }

}
```

Comment: Код в студию. После метода ран вообще ничего запускать не получится

Answer (score 0):

Для запуска периодических задач в Java наряду с таймерами, есть специальная абстракция `ScheduledExecutorService`, которая содержит методы `schedule`, `scheduleAtFixedRate` и `scheduleWithFixedDelay` все они возвращают `ScheduledFuture` - результат выполнения асинхронной задачи, абстракция для возможности отменить задачу или узнать о ее успешном выполнении, получить результат итд.

---

```
    ScheduledExecutorService s = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    s.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Код выше будет выводить время в консоль примерно раз в 3 секунды, 1 из задержки указанной при запуске таймера, еще 2 от `Thread.sleep`